# How to implement scrolling functionality in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, keyboard, scroll, uitextview

I am using a UITextView which is simply not capable of scrolling if the text expands beneath the keyboard as can be seen in the picture below. Therefor I need some sort of scrolling that scrolls down the view if the text is in line with or beneath the keyboard. I have looked for similar examples/tutorials but not found any good ones working for my project.

I will post just how I have implemented my UITextView* commentField below in my .h file. What shall I do from here? If you can be a specific with example code it would be appreciated!. /Regards

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=kck6t&s=6

ReportViewController.h file:

```
@interface ReportViewController : MLUIViewController <MLReportErrorDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{

IBOutlet UITextView *commentField;
IBOutlet UITextField *emailField;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *commentField;
```

ReportViewController.m file:

```
- (void) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)commentField
{
???????????????????????
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the textView to fully visible when typing. I think you cannot dynamically scroll when the text is going beneath to keyboard.

You can do it by using the following code.

```
//—-resize the scroll view (with keyboard)—-
CGRect viewFrame = [scrollView frame];
viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardRect.size.height;
scrollView.frame = viewFrame;

//—-scroll to the current text field—-
CGRect textFieldRect = [yourTextView frame];
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [iPhone Keyboard Hides TextField](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/tutorial/iphone/iPhone-Keyboard-Hides-TextField.html)